# Get android codename from model with the jq tool

Tags: json, jq

Trying to get the codename of a specific android device having its model and brand from https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidDeviceNames :

```bash
$ brand=ACER
$ model=B3-A20B
$ \curl -Ls https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidDeviceNames/raw/master/json/manufacturers/$brand.json | \
jq ".devices[].codename | select( .devices[].model == \"$model\" )" 
jq: error (at <stdin>:1114): Cannot index string with string "devices"
$ echo $?
5
```

EDIT 1 : For those who could be interested, I've written this little bash function in my `.bash_functions` thanks to @jeff-mercado :

```bash
getCodeName () {
    if [ $# != 2 ]; then
        echo "=> Usage: $FUNCNAME brand model" >&2
        return 1
    fi

    local brand=$1
    local model=$2
    local codeNameJSONDataBaseURL=https://github.com/jaredrummler/AndroidDeviceNames/raw/master/json/manufacturers
    local curl="$(which curl) -sL"

    $curl $codeNameJSONDataBaseURL/$brand.json | jq -r --arg model $model '.devices[] | select( .model | match($model;"i") ).codename'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By having a pipe between filters, you're changing the input context to the value(s) produced from the previous filters. By the time you reach the `select/1` call, the input is the codename values. You need to keep the context to the device first, select based on the model, then get the codename.

```
$ ... | jq --arg model "$model" '.devices[] | select(.model == $model).codename'
```

Comment: Now I understand, at last :)